# How to connect Django-cms to react froentend and perform get, put , post and delete operation?

Tags: django-cms

how to connect Djangocms to the react or other frontend API
How to post, put and delete data in Django cms by using rest API or cms.API?

Comment: See docs: https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/topics/frontend-integration.html and https://vinitkumar.me/2018-05-24-React-With-Django-CMS/